# How can I adapt my radius search by postcode/zipcode to radius search by town?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlgeography, geographic-distance

We currently have a working script to return a list of all our products within a radius of a postcode/zipcode. It searches for all products that have locations in area codes within the *@miles* parameter of *@lookingfor* postcode, also returning the distance.

The *PostodeLocation* table contains four columns: the town/city, the postcode (pcd) and the Northing (grn) and Easting (gre) grid references. The primary key is on the postcode.

The problem is: I do not know the centre centre of each town or the postcodes for the outer radius of each town. I cannot adapt the script to give me all products in locations within a radius of a town, or even a town centre.

Has anybody else encountered this requirement and found a solution? I'm looking for a technique more than the actual code requirement.

Current script:

```
declare @lookingfor nvarchar(10) = 'sw1a 1aa'
declare @miles int = 5
DECLARE @UserCoordX bigint
DECLARE @UserCoordY bigint
SELECT    @UserCoordX = GRE
        , @UserCoordY = GRN
FROM MyCompany.dbo.PostcodeLocations pcls
WHERE pcls.PCD = @lookingfor
select pcls.PCD
    , p.ProdName
    , sqrt((((pcls.GRE - @UserCoordX) * (pcls.GRE - @UserCoordX)) + ((pcls.GRN - @UserCoordY) * (pcls.GRN - @UserCoordY)))/(160.9334*160.9334)) as Distance
from MyCompany.dbo.pcls_disk pcls
inner join MyCompany.dbo.Loc l on l.Postcode = pcls.pcd
inner join MyCompany.dbo.X_ProdLoc xpl on xpl.LocId = l.LocId
inner join MyCompany.dbo.Prod p on p.ProdId = xpl.ProdId
where p.StatusId = 4 and p.HideFromSearch = 0
and ((pcls.GRE - @UserCoordX) * (pcls.GRE - @UserCoordX)) + ((pcls.GRN - @UserCoordY) * (pcls.GRN - @UserCoordY)) 
        <= cast(@Miles * 160.9334 * @Miles * 160.9334 as bigint)
order by [Distance]
```

Comment: How about defining quadrilaterals that fall within cities and holding them as data?  It's a big amount of data to prepare, so has anyone done this I wonder.  You could store coordinates of all major town centres I suppose - also no small amount of data to prepare.

Comment: @Cato I have thought about obtaining a list of dead centre postcodes, but unable to find them. I could calculate by averaging the minimum and maximum northern/earstern coords and adding the largest number to the radius. The displayed distance would then be the distance found minus the largest north/eastern amount, making negatives zero. It is, however, not accurate for irregular towns/cities; quadrilaterals would have the same problem.

Comment: Take the average X and average Y co-ordinate for a postal district